# Fill div to viewport height makes extra space in Chrome not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Please do have a look at http://workbench2.axaumzug.ch/ in Firefox and Chrome. As can be seen from the live example and the images, Chrome seems to add extra space at the bottom somehow or the entire page.

[image: Space in Chrome on bottom of viewport]
[image: Space in Chrome on top of viewport]

I have researched how to make a div expand to the bottom of the viewport. The references are in the source. Not tested this in Safari. Seem to work fine in Firefox though. What am I doing wrong or is this a bug?

Is there a way to accomplish this to not have space at the bottom in Chrome through jQuery somehow? I am currently looking into http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ to see if something like that could help. If you have any ideas or can confirm this is a bug, please do let me know.

edit:

[image: Firefox Chrome comparison extra space]

To make this more clear and understandable here is a third image that compares both Firefox and Chrome directly. As you can see Firefox does not have a space between the scrollbar and the bottom whereas Chrome does have one, and the space also actually changes depending on how the Chrome browser window is sized.

When I remove the borders from the body and tabs Firefox is exactly at the bottom of the page with the scrollbar and Chrome is not. The source is the same.

Why does Chrome add extra space to the bottom on the site? Where does this space come from and how can I address it purely in Chrome?

I hope it is 100% clear now what I am asking or what I am trying to understand.

As TimPalmer mentioned so nicely, there seems to be 68px in height that is added. This happens regardless of if there are headers or other elements or not. And this is exactly the point I am getting at. Does anyone have a clue why Chrome is doing this? Can I addess this issue when using outerHeight (true) instead of height in jQuery?

Comment: If someone can let me know how this is not researched or unclear I will try and edit the question to make it better. Thought giving a live example, including images, commenting the source (have you seen the references to the other questions on stack in the source, have you actually checked the source??) and asking to compare between Firefox and Chrome would make this perfectly clear. Help me make this more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome did add extra space regardless of elements being above the nav tabs or not and regardless of the $(window).height() function. It was working all along the way in Firefox, remember?

Since the code uses HTML5 tags I simply included the HTML5 Doctor CSS reset http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/#the-scripts and it now works perfectly without changing the $(window).height() function and regardless of having extra elements above the nav, both in Firefox and Chrome.

When you now click on any of the tab links and the content of the tab is not enough to reach the bottom of the viewport, first of all the tab content (pane) expands nicely to the bottom of the viewport both in Firefox and Chrome and last not least there is not a single pixel of space left between the bottom of the scrollbar and the bottom of the viewport in Chrome.

It was a matter of Chrome default styles that needed to be reset. The code/logic was fine all along the way. The only change I applied was scrollTop: $('.li-nav'), so that it really scrolls up directly to the top of the nav-tabs instead of leaving 1 pixel space above it.

After getting voted down for an IMO researched, documented question, with images and a live example and much work I am glad to see I can sort these things myself. Feels good! Thanks for your input TimPalmer!

To the voter, next time you vote down, read the question and if you don't get it look at the source and the example and the images instead of just clicking buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
headingSpace = 68;
windowHeight = ($(window).height()) - headingSpace);
$('#content-wrapper').css('min-height', windowHeight);
```

You need to offset the height of #content-wrapper by the height of the two headings.
There will be more elegant ways of doing this, such as wrapping the headers in a div and measuring said div, but this will get you going at least

Comment: 68 is the height of your headings according to Chrome dev tools

Comment: Putting the headers in a div would make a difference in both Firefox and Chrome? Thing is the site is what I want it to be in Firefox, though Chrome renders it different, regardless of the headers. That is what I am trying to find out. Why is Chrome adding extra space really? Ideally, when clicking a tab with a pane with less content, the pane should stretch to the bottom of the viewport and the scrollbar should not have any space left to scroll down to. This is not the case in Chrome like can be seen. If I wrap the headers (and other elements) in a div should I use outerHeight instead?

Comment: @lowtechsun The workbench that you have shared has the same issue in both chrome and firefox for me.

Comment: The issue is definitely there. The 1 px additional space in Firefox is gone with scrollTop: $('.li-nav'). Chrome still does show the extra space, regardless of scrollTop: $('.li-nav'), with or without borders in the css. However I found the solution, see updated workbench and solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure what you are trying to do, but a CSS trick to make a div the full size of your screen is this:

```
.myDiv{
   position: absolute;
   Top: 0px;   
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Added one more image to better show the difference between Firefox and Chrome. You can compare it yourself with the live link and see it for yourself as well if you like. Making a div expand to the bottom of the viewport is not what I am asking. I am asking where the extra space is coming from in Chrome that is not there in Firefox. Hope this helps understanding what I am trying to learn.